# Set Date Criteria in getContentResolver().query for Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-studio, cursor

I use

```
Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox")
```

when executing

```
getContentResolver().query
```

I want a selection that will always return messages from within the last 10 days of the current system date. Please help with the correct SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassing to have to answer my own question but here goes...

```
long daterr = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 10L * 24 * 3600*1000).getTime();



Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"}, "Date > ? ", new String[]{""+daterr}, "date ASC");
```